# WCF Data Services - adding state data to response headers

Tags: wcf-data-services

I have an existing web application that I want to wrap with WCF Data Services, to give it an OData input/output formatting.

so far I've been able to send requests with credentials, and retrieve desired data.
I'm able to plant credentials in request header - but no clue how to send values back,
such as stateId(=string), to be consumed by the client.
Altering metadata in order to send stateId is not an option, of course.

Can I control the header of the response? 
Is this my best solution?

Comment: Quick question - do you want to add a extra header in the response? If yes, assuming you are using WCF Data services, You can override OnStartProcessingRequest method - in the args, you can do args.OperationContext.ResponseHeaders and add a response header. Does this help?

Comment: and how do I open a request header from .net client?